# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.Retrofit$Builder

Tags: java, gson, retrofit, retrofit2

I have a problem, i don't understand , my code work fine in Lollipop but in Kitkak crash.

The exception it's

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.Retrofit$Builder
```

Dependencies

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

Log

```
/com.gob.gep.exa.example/AndroidRuntime:FATALEXCEPTION:main
Process:com.gob.gep.sfa.dds.autopue,PID:3543
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:retrofit.Retrofit$Builder
atcom.gob.gep.sfa.dds.autopue.Servicios.WsConsultaDisponibilidad.<init>(WsConsultaDisponibilidad.java:68)
atcom.gob.gep.sfa.dds.autopue.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:93)
atandroid.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
atandroid.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
atandroid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(NativeMethod)
atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
atdalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeMethod)
com.gob.gep.exa.example/dalvikvm:Couldnotfindclass'retrofit.Retrofit$Builder',referencedfrommethodcom.gob.gep.sfa.dds.autopue.Servicios.WsConsultaDisponibilidad.<init>
com.gob.gep.exa.example/dalvikvm:Couldnotfindclass'org.kxml2.kdom.Element',referencedfrommethodcom.gob.gep.sfa.dds.autopue.Servicios.WsConsultaDisponibilidad.buildAuthHeader
com.gob.gep.exa.example/dalvikvm:Couldnotfindclass'retrofit.Retrofit$Builder',referencedfrommethodcom.gob.gep.sfa.dds.autopue.Servicios.WsConsultaDisponibilidad.<init>
com.gob.gep.exa.example/dalvikvm:Couldnotfindclass'org.kxml2.kdom.Element',referencedfrommethodcom.gob.gep.sfa.dds.autopue.Servicios.WsConsultaDisponibilidad.buildAuthHeader
```

Comment: Looks like the group is wrong on your converter-gson dependency.  Shouldn't it also be retrofit2?  Also looks like it's released and you could move to 2.0.0 or 2.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dependencies looks wrong.

It should be

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.1'
```

Version(`2.0.1`) and groupId(`com.squareup.retrofit2`) should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

after spending too much time i found following solution around this 
extend your application class with MultiDexApplication
and add following dependency in your build.gradle

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```